# html5 get file path

Tags: php, javascript, html

Using html5 javascript, how do you get the file path when user select the file?
I needed the file path to use in this example case:

user upload a file, pause it(I know so far I think only mozilla can do this), and then close the browser and plan to resume the file the next day. I need to know the file path for this file..

Comment: You won't be able to re-initiate a file upload like that anyways.

Comment: is there any other programming language that able to reiiniate file upload aside from java..

Comment: Anything that can do this will have to have a plugin of some sort.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even if you did have a path (some browsers used to give it to you), there is no way to set the path of a input of type file.

<strike>Therefore, it is not possible to do what you want with plain JS and the DOM.</strike>

I said it wasn't possible, but now that you asked I do think there is a way, with new File API. The following steps outline what needs to be done, but have in no way been tested, and I don't expect it to work, it's just to show you the way, also global variables are bad, it's just the simplest way to show you. Here's a good page with examples on using the File API http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

**First** You need an input of type file, then you can use once a user selects a file, you are given access to the File object. http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/#dfn-filereader

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<script>
  var fileBlobs = [];
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // files is a FileList of File objects. You may now read their contents
    var reader = new FileReader();
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
      fileBlobs.push(reader.readAsBinaryString(f));
    }
  }    
  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

**Second** Now you have the content as a binary string. You can use the File API to store the file locally in a way that you can access later using the FileWriter and FileSaver interfaces http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/file-writer.html

```
var bb = new BlobBuilder();
bb.appendfileBlobs.(fileBlobs[0]);
window.saveAs(bb.getBlob(), "test_file");
```

**Third** You need to make an Ajax request passing that blob to the server, tracking how much of the upload is complete. http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-upload-attribute. It doesn't look like tracking progress can be done on the client. Your may have to poll the server for actual progress. A possible solution to know where to start an interrupted upload is to have upload ids and when you restart an upload, you ask the server how much of the file has been uploaded.

Sorry I can't provide a full answer, but this is not an easy problem. The steps I gave you should  take you in the right direction.

Comment: @JuanMendes.. so is there anyway to do this pause/resume function aside from using java / flash ? I figured that HTML5 has FileAPI so I thought that we can do it through html

Comment: @user1096900 Take a look at my revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

Much like you can't submit an HTTP request in pieces over several days, you can't do it with file uploads as well. The protocol just won't allow it. Hence the entire effort is futile.

Comment: but can we kind of trick it? using the slice from html5 File API to upload part by part

Comment: HTML5 as powerful as it would ever be, will never be able to override what the HTTP directs. The protocol is set by the server, not the client.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, that isn't possible as Javascript only has access to files that were shared with it through either a `file` input or drag-and-drop.